# Copying file with the same name from different directories to the directory before

Tags: command-line, directory, cp

I have a set of 120 files, all with the same name,`contig.fa` which are located in the hierarchy of

```
Main Directory 1
   Subdirectory 1 
     file.fa
Main Directory 2 
   Subdirectory 2
     file.fa
```

I want to copy the `file.fa` to the `Main Directory`. I've tried several bash loops to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command finds all files named `file.fa` and copies them to their parent directory.

```
find -type f -name "file.fa" -execdir cp "{}" ../ \;
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the job.